# Determine batch size during `tensorflow.keras` Custom Class `call` method

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, layer

I already asked this question [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/115899/determine-batch-size-during-tensorflow-keras-custom-class-call-method), but I thought StackOverflow would have more traffic/people that might know the answer.

I'm building a custom keras Layer similar to an example found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object).  I want the `call` method inside the class to be able to know what the `batch_size` of the `inputs` data flowing through the method is, but the `inputs.shape` is showing as `(None, 3)` during model prediction.  Here's a concrete example:

I initialize a simple data set like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model

# Create fake data to use for model testing
n = 1000
np.random.seed(123)
x1 = np.random.random(n)
x2 = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=n)
x3 = np.random.lognormal(0, 1, size=n)

X = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate([
    np.reshape(x1, (-1, 1)),
    np.reshape(x2, (-1, 1)),
    np.reshape(x3, (-1, 1)),
], axis=1))
```

Then I define a custom class to test/show what I'm talking about:

```py
class TestClass(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(TestClass, self).get_config()
        return config

    def call(self, inputs: tf.Tensor):
        if inputs.dtype.base_dtype != self._compute_dtype_object.base_dtype:
            inputs = tf.cast(inputs, dtype=self._compute_dtype_object)

        print(inputs)
        record_count, n = inputs.shape
        print(f'inputs.shape = {inputs.shape}')

        return inputs
```

Then, when I create a simple model and force it to do a forward pass...

```py
input_layer = layers.Input(3)
test = TestClass()(input_layer)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00025)
model = Model(input_layer, test)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
model.predict(X.loc[:9, :])
```

... I get this output printed to the screen

```
model.predict(X.loc[:9, :])
Tensor("model_1/Cast:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32)
inputs.shape = (None, 3)
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step
Out[34]: 
array([[ 0.5335418 ,  0.7788839 ,  0.64132416],
       [ 0.2924202 , -0.08321562,  0.412311  ],
       [ 0.5118007 , -0.6822934 ,  1.1782378 ],
       [ 0.03780456, -0.19350041,  0.7637337 ],
       [ 0.86494124, -3.196387  ,  4.8535166 ],
       [ 0.26708454, -0.49397194,  0.91296834],
       [ 0.49734482, -1.6618049 ,  0.50054324],
       [ 0.8563762 ,  0.7956695 ,  0.29466265],
       [ 0.7682351 ,  0.86538637,  0.6633331 ],
       [ 0.85322225,  0.868021  ,  0.1776046 ]], dtype=float32)
```

You can see that during the `model.predict` call the `inputs.shape` prints out a value of `(None, 3)`, but obviously that's not true since the `call` method returns an output with a shape of `(10, 3)`.  How can I capture the `10` value in this example while in the `call` method?

#### UPDATE 1

When I use `tf.shape` as suggested in the current answer, I can print the value to the screen, but I get an error when I try to capture that value in a variable.

```py
class TestClass(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(TestClass, self).get_config()
        return config

    def call(self, inputs: tf.Tensor):
        if inputs.dtype.base_dtype != self._compute_dtype_object.base_dtype:
            inputs = tf.cast(inputs, dtype=self._compute_dtype_object)
        record_count, n = tf.shape(inputs)
        tf.print("Dynamic batch size", tf.shape(inputs)[0])
        return inputs
```

This code causes an error on the `record_count, ...` line.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/opt/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3378, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-22-104d812c32e6>", line 1, in <module>
    test = TestClass()(input_layer)
  File "/Users/username/opt/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/Users/username/opt/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 692, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Exception encountered when calling layer "test_class_4" (type TestClass).
in user code:
    File "<ipython-input-21-2dec1d5b9547>", line 12, in call  *
        record_count, n = tf.shape(inputs)
    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.
Call arguments received by layer "test_class_4" (type TestClass):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32)
```

I tried decorating the `call` method with `@tf.function`, but I get the same error.

#### UPDATE 2

I tried a couple other things and found that, oddly, tensorflow doesn't seem to like the tuple assignment.  It seems to work fine if it's coded like this instead.

```py
class TestClass(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(TestClass, self).get_config()
        return config

    def call(self, inputs: tf.Tensor):
        if inputs.dtype.base_dtype != self._compute_dtype_object.base_dtype:
            inputs = tf.cast(inputs, dtype=self._compute_dtype_object)
        shape = tf.shape(inputs)
        record_count = shape[0]
        n = shape[1]
        tf.print("Dynamic batch size", tf.shape(inputs)[0])
        return inputs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** --> Use `tf.shape(inputs)[0]` if you want to capture dynamic batch size in `call` method, or you can just use static batch size which can be specified in model creation.

---

Under the hood TensorFlow decorates `call` and `__call__` (that's what `call` method *calls*) method with `tf.function`. Using `print` and `.shape` will not work as expected.

With `tf.function` python codes are traced and converted to native TensorFlow operations. After that, a static graph is created, this is just an instance of [tf.Graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph). In the end, the operations are executed in that graph.

Python's `print` function only considered in the first step only, so this is not the correct way to print things in graph mode (decorated with `tf.function`).

Tensor shapes are dynamic in runtime so you need to use `tf.shape(inputs)[0]` which will give you the batch size for that batch.

If you really want to see that `10` in `call`:

```
class TestClass(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(TestClass, self).get_config()
        return config

    def call(self, inputs: tf.Tensor):
        if inputs.dtype.base_dtype != self._compute_dtype_object.base_dtype:
            inputs = tf.cast(inputs, dtype=self._compute_dtype_object)
        tf.print("Dynamic batch size", tf.shape(inputs)[0])
        return inputs
```

Running:

```
input_layer = layers.Input(3)
test = TestClass()(input_layer)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00025)
model = Model(input_layer, test)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
model.predict(X.loc[:9, :])
```

Will return:

```
Dynamic batch size 10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 65ms/step
array([[ 6.9646919e-01, -1.0032653e-02,  3.7556963e+00],
       [ 2.8613934e-01, -8.4564441e-01,  9.9685013e-01],
       [ 2.2685145e-01,  9.1146064e-01,  6.5008003e-01],
       [ 5.5131477e-01, -1.3744969e+00,  8.6379850e-01],
       [ 7.1946895e-01, -5.4706562e-01,  3.1904945e+00],
       [ 4.2310646e-01, -7.5526608e-05,  5.2649558e-01],
       [ 9.8076421e-01, -1.2116680e-01,  7.4064606e-01],
       [ 6.8482971e-01, -2.0085855e+00,  5.3138912e-01],
       [ 4.8093191e-01, -9.2064655e-01,  8.1520426e-01],
       [ 3.9211753e-01,  1.6823435e-01,  1.2382457e+00]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: your solution allows me to print the value to the screen, but doesn't seem to work when I want to store that value in a local variable.

Comment: As far as I know, unpacking dynamic shapes not supported by Autograph, that's why I wrote `tf.shape[0]`. You need to index them as I did.